# Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Store<State>' ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular5, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm trying to use the property 'take' when selecting a state in my feature but I'm getting the error `Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Store<State>`. Please, anyone has a clue of what is going on? The reason I want to do that is because I have to identify when the user clicked on the button "Add space" which changes my template to a form. As this mode also changes the parent's template, I'm managing it with @ngrx/store.

My code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

    import { Space } from '../../../shared/space.model';
    // import { SpacesService } from '../../spaces.service';
    import * as SpacesActions from '../../store/spaces.actions';
    import * as fromSpaces from '../../store/spaces.reducers';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-space-item',
      templateUrl: './space-item.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./space-item.component.scss']
    })
    export class SpaceItemComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      @Input() space: Space;
      @Input() index: number;
      private addMode: boolean;
      private editMode = false;
      // updatedSpaceName: string;
      // updatedSpace: Space;
      private subscription: Subscription;
      updatedSpaceName: string;
      updatedPicture: string;

      constructor(
                  // private spacesService: SpacesService,
                  private store: Store<fromSpaces.FeatureState>) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.store.select('spaces')
          .take(1)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              if (data.addMode) {
                this.addMode = data.addMode;
              } else {
                this.addMode = false;
              }
            }
          );
      }
      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

      onEnableEdit() {
        this.editMode = true;

        this.updatedSpaceName = this.space.name;
        this.updatedPicture = this.space.picture;
        // console.log(this.updatedSpace);

      }
      onUpdate() {
        this.onCancelEdit();
        const updatedSpace = new Space(this.updatedSpaceName, this.updatedPicture);
        // this.spacesService.updateSpace(updatedSpace, this.index);
        this.store.dispatch(new SpacesActions.UpdateSpace({index: this.index, updatedSpace}));
      }

      onCancelEdit() {
        this.editMode = false;
        // this.updatedSpace = this.space;
      }

      onCancelAdd() {
        // this.spacesService.addModeActivated.next(false);
        this.store.dispatch(new SpacesActions.SwitchAddMode(false));
      }

      onDelete() {
        // this.spacesService.deleteSpace(this.index);
        this.store.dispatch(new SpacesActions.DeleteSpace(this.index));
      }

      onAddSpace(form: NgForm) {
        const value = form.value;
        const newSpace: Space = new Space(value.spaceName);

        // this.spacesService.addSpace(newSpace);
        this.store.dispatch(new SpacesActions.AddSpace(newSpace));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try to import it

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
```

for **Angular > 6**, Angular app bundle size are reduced using lettable operators, because they are **tree-shakable**

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

this.store.select('spaces').pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 29):

In case of angular 6:

1) import from rxjs

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

2) use it with `pipe` method

```
.pipe(take(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

is a compatibility problem with the latest version of angular, you need rxjs-compat.

solution:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Comment: For Angular8, this worked for me. I think it is must to install rxjs-compat